# count down timer freeze in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

We used the jpages script for pagination. Refer: http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/

the `init()` function freeze the countdown timer.  We used countdown.js for timer.

Normally the timer is working fine. But when the `init()` function is called it freezed.

Any solution to fix this?

---

**Update:**

Please see the following location: http://vsoftdemos.com/test_chrome.html

It is a google chrome specific issue and it works good on all the other browsers. Here are the steps to duplicate this issue.

Once you load this page on google chrome you can see that the timer is working. Then please open a new tab and past the url and click enter button. Now the timer stops running and if you refresh the page it works again.

If I comment a line in http://vsoftdemos.com/jPages.js it works good. The line that I commented is  `this.init();`

I hope I explained everything clearly.

Comment: not without seeing any code no

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: There's probably a solution to this problem, yes... [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Jan set up a jsFiddle then

Comment: I had a look through that [jPages documentation](http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/documentation.html) and I can't see an init method anywhere, are you sure that's not for the countdown?

Comment: I am preparing the code set and let me post it in a few minutes. Thanks for your comments

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: @Dale Can you please check the URL and help? Thanks

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P Very strange, the first time I visited the page it froze, I refreshed and it worked!? I'm in Chrome 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK having looked through your demo pages code all I can suggest is to reorder your script a little.

Move this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jPages.js"></script>
```

Into the head section

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_001.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jPages.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then combine your other scripts (and tweak them a little)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("div.holder").jPages({
            containerID : "itemContainer",
            callback: function(pages, items)
            {
                init_timer();
            }
        });

        function init_timer()
        {
            $('.countbox1041').countdown({
                layout : '<b>{d<}{dnn}D:{d>}' + '{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}</b>',
                timeSeparator : ':',
                onExpiry : function () {
                },
                until : 100000
            });
        }

        init_timer();

    });
</script>
```

Now as this script was working for me, I can only assume that because the countdown div is inside the jpages div, the jpages script is having some adverse effect on the timer, I've added a callback to the jpages code that triggers the timer every time the page is turned (or whatever it does)

Hope this helps

Comment: Ahh it doesn't fix it. I have updated my code for your review. Please check it and let me know. Thanks http://vsoftdemos.com/test_chrome.html

Comment: Like I said mate the code works for me, even your original code, so I haven't got a clue what's going on for you

Comment: As you said in your comment it froze on the first time and working good on the refresh. That is the problem.